# How to query arguments for a callback method

Tags: javascript, function, callback

I am making a reduce function that uses another function, which takes multiple arguments, as a callback. My question is, if I wish to test the callback function for whether an argument exists, what syntax would I need to use.

```
var result = _.reduce([1,2,3], function(memo) {
      return memo;
 }); 

_.reduce = function(arr, fun, opt){
      //if(arguments[1][1] == undefined) return arr[0];
```

The last line is my best attempt. What I am trying to say is that, if the function in the result line has no second argument, return arr[0].

Comment: You seem to be looking for [`fun.length`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/length) - but notice that whether or not a parameter is declared doesn't have to imply whether the argument is used. Don't do magic with it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to access the arguments inside a function call. You can use the arguments object for this.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/length

It allows you to iterate through the arguments of a function and do something with them. For example -

```
function yourCustomReduceFunction() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    console.log(arguments[i]);
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I don't think that will work in my case. I am trying to access the arguments of a callback function inside another function. Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the code you wrote will return the arguments from the mother function, not the callback function.

Comment: Could you not just wire the loop into your callback function then? The arguments object should still work.

Comment: Martin - Are you saying to make a method inside of the callback to pass the arguments? That kinda makes sense.